# HTTPS or other clever authentication methods

Tags: security, authentication, web-applications, https

A little background: I am going to be constructing a webserver, likely the most up to date version of apache when I get around to it. It is going to be updated with sensory information from a makeshift security system I have.

As a counterpart, I am designing an app to go along with it, that will automatically contact the webserver and pull the sensory information about once every 1.5 minutes.

I want to have an authentication method so that the average Bob can't see this information, mostly due to the fact that there will be some command and control as part of the server as well.

The question: I feel like a simple username and password is the wrong way to go about this since it isn't dynamic and theoretically seeing the same credentials sent that frequent could be dangerous, so is there any other authentication method that could mitigate this?

The question pt. 2:  Obviously I want an encrypted channel, will https stumble over itself if it tries to renegotiate every minute and a half?

I haven't begun this project yet much less chosen any language to write it in, meaning I am super open minded to suggestions, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1. once every one and a half minutes is no load at all for a http server, no issues with https there. 2. you could take a llok at client side certificates if you want to make things really secure (expensive) or you could limit requests by configured IP addresses, but that will only work for static addresses. But most important: what you describe is a pretty big project. Sure you realize the amount of work waiting for you?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I have a handle on the scope of this project. I'm certainly willing to put the effort in to get this as secure as possible with as little cost. I've done a project that was similar before, but without the authentication and security.

Comment: I've considered approaching it from the trusted IP realm, but since it will be on my android, that simply couldn't work. The only other way I could think of is maybe set up a VPN on the same machine and contact the webserver though the local host, but that is bound to become cumbersome and frankly have no idea how I could automate that (if at all) from the android client side. I haven't considered client side certificates yet, why do you say expensive?

Comment: A good question, I have to admit that I have only limited experience. I wrote "expensive" due to the fact that certificates need to be signed to make sense, to be signed by a trusted authority. That is why you typically have to pay to be able to setup an https server correctly. I assumed that you'd have to pay for each client certificate as well, since each has to be signed after creation. however the more I think about it the more I agree that this is not true: you can create an own CA and sign yourself. Since you know the CA you can trust it. That differs from the https example...

Comment: However such client side certificate should _not_ be the only means of authentication, since certificates can be copied and stolen without this getting noticed. So yes, they offer an elegant option to raise security and identify clients, but they should not get overrated.

Comment: Hm... really looks like I have to hack some project to gain experience in that... :-)

Comment: I think you're right on the money with issuing your own client side certs as your own CA. After poking a bit more around SE it seems as if not only is it possible, but its preffered in a lot of instances. When coupled with typical http authentication this could very well be the route to go. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, sorry, seems I was unclear in this point: I did not want to doubt that, in contrary! With "I agree that this is not true" I meant I have to revise my statement: it clearly does work and make sense. No doubt at all there.

Answer (score 0):

> The question: I feel like a simple username and password is the wrong
>   way to go about this since it isn't dynamic and theoretically seeing
>   the same credentials sent that frequent could be dangerous, so is
>   there any other authentication method that could mitigate this?

You could use [Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/) to allow log on via a Google account.

Or you could implement two factor authentication with say [Google Authenticator](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/04/add-two-factor-authentication-to-your-website-with-google-authenticator-and-twilio-sms.html) or via SMS to prove that the user logging in has more than one factor of authentication. These factors could be:

- Something you know (e.g. password)
- Something you have (e.g. phone that provides a One Time Password)

**Edit**: Having re-read your question - yes you are fine to authenticate with username and password (over HTTPS), however you should then store a session identifier client-side and simply send this in future rather than the username/password each time. This is more secure as it can be stored safely client-side, and if exposed the identifier can be easily revoked.

> The question pt. 2: Obviously I want an encrypted channel, will https
>   stumble over itself if it tries to renegotiate every minute and a half?

Nope, this is what it is designed for. Browsers will keep open an HTTPS connection for a length of time. Additionally, they will use session resumption rather than executing a full HTTPS handshake in the case that a new connection needs to be established. Session resumption is much quicker than establishing a completely new session. See [this article on the CloudFlare blog](https://blog.cloudflare.com/tls-session-resumption-full-speed-and-secure/) for more info.

Comment: Good resources. Thank you. Out of curiosity are you familiar with any VPN api for android devices? I was also talking to someone above about issuing client side certs as your own CA. Would this be a good method to ensure someone is who they are when combined with HTTP authentication (in case the cert was stolen)?